# Google maps Census tract

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, census

I have searched the Google map documentation for an option to return the US census tract, but haven't had any luck. I know they have a site where you can search for it by address [census google maps](https://mapsengine.google.com/10446176163891957399-08480965393178305537-4/mapview/?authuser=0). However I haven't found a way to access that service. I am looking for a google map api that at least would return the census tract. I also searched in the [google maps geocoding documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#Sensor) but the json result doesn't seem to return the census tract. Does anyone know if this is possible, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/combining-data

Interesting is the section of **Importing data from the US Census API**.

Answer (score 1):

The Census Bureau has a batch facility called the GeoCoder, https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/

It allows you to submit addresses or lat-long in batches of 10,000. Not sure if they have an API. Note that the site is wonky - sometimes just fails to respond for hours at a time.

I have not compared the address match efficiency of Census vs Google. But if Google were better, you might send the addresses first to Google, then send those lat-longs to GeoCoder.

Big upvote for the Census data which @RonTLV points to above. Rich and detailed.